# "Connection refused" error for google geo coding

Tags: java, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I worte a 'java' program to get coordinates(latitude and longitude) for a given postalcode using geocoding. 
I tested that program at my home it is working fine, but when i run the same program in my office it is throwing 'network error'. the stack trace is like below.

> [2012-10-04 10:50:34.337 MESZ] [main] ERROR
>   com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder - Connection refused: connect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:213) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316) ~[na:1.7.0_03]
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1035)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_03]    at
>   com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder.request(Geocoder.java:72)
>   ~[geocoder-java-0.9.jar:na]   at
>   com.google.code.geocoder.Geocoder.geocode(Geocoder.java:63)
>   ~[geocoder-java-0.9.jar:na]   at
>   de.dmc.intersport.enfinity.ch.b2c.app.capi.GoogleGeoLocation.getGeoResults(GoogleGeoLocation.java:36)
>   [lib/:na]     at
>   de.dmc.intersport.enfinity.ch.b2c.app.capi.GoogleGeoLocation.(GoogleGeoLocation.java:21)
>   [lib/:na]     at
>   de.dmc.intersport.enfinity.ch.b2c.app.capi.GoogleGeoLocation.main(GoogleGeoLocation.java:67)
>   [lib/:na]

I think it is the problem with 'firewall setting'. What can i do to get rid of this.
Any help will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to the above problem, one has to set proxy setting like below in you r java code

> System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "proxyname");
>     System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "portnumber");

then things should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you don't have sufficient rights to connect with **Google Geo Coding API** from your office computer due to **firewall restrictions**. That's why you are facing ***"network error"*** from the same program that you successfully run before at your home. Try to run the same application/program on other computer where no firewall restriction exist.

Either you can take help from your company's Network Administrator to ***bypass*** Firewall restrictions from your computer's **IP**.